# Redux State Not Updating With No Error Messages

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having a weird issue where I can see my action creator being triggered upon mouse click, but the state just does not "seem" to be updating. I also receive no error messages that could help me debug this.

The portion of state I am trying to work with is very simple, by default it is set to false, and can also be true upon certain conditions. Here is what I see upon initial render in my console after a click, that **should** change the "detail" boolean to true:

[image]

Here is my Redux connected component called "Journey":

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Header from '../Header'
import AccessibilityBar from '../AccessibilityBar'
import AdditionalItemsBar from '../AdditionalItemsBar'

import Armenia from './Armenia'
import Holocaust from './Holocaust'
import Rwanda from './Rwanda'
import Detail from '../Detail'

export class Journey extends Component {

  render() {
    const { match, detail } = this.props
    console.log('Current value of detail: ' + detail)

    return (
      <div className="journey">
        <Header />
        <AccessibilityBar />

        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${match.url}/:armenia`} component={Armenia} />
          <Route path={`${match.url}/:holocaust`} component={Holocaust} />
          <Route path={`${match.url}/:rwanda`} component={Rwanda} />
        </Switch>

        <img src="./img/left-caret.svg"  style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '375px', left: '15px' }}/>
        <img src="./img/right-caret.svg"  style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '375px', right: '15px' }}/>

        {
          detail ? <Detail /> : null
        }

        <AdditionalItemsBar />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    detail: state.detail
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Journey)
```

The action creator:

```
import { TOGGLE_DETAIL } from './types'

export function toggleDetail() {
  console.log('toggle action creator runs...')
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_DETAIL,
    payload: true
  }
}
```

The reducer:

```
import { TOGGLE_DETAIL } from '../actions/types'

export default function(state = false, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_DETAIL:
      return action.payload
  }
  return state
}
```

I have a reusable component called, "ImageBlock", that has multiple instances of itself on a single view that actually triggers the action creator. Here is the code for that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleDetail } from '../../actions/detail'

export class ImageBlock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.props} className="image-block" onClick={this.props.toggleDetail}>
        <img src="./img/text-icon.svg" className="text-hint"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
    toggleDetail
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageBlock)
```

**PS** To give you more insight of what exactly the view looks like, here is a screenshot of it. As you can see, the red blocks, are each an instance of ImageBlock. When they are clicked, they trigger the action creator.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you set a debugger in the state manager (in your switch) to check that it actually goes in there. Also I like to add a default value to my switch statements instead of a return right after, so have a default switch case that just returns the state untouched.

Comment: try making `mapDispatchToprops` an object of actions instead of a function that returns that object.

Comment: Yeah I did that, the reducer definitely isnt receiving the action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are simply calling the action but you are not dispatching it, how would your manager know that a certain action has been triggered if there's no dispatching ?

One way to do it is using `bindActionCreators` as follows:

```
...
import * as actions from '/path/to/actions';

...

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  myActions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
});
...
```

As per docs:

`bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)`

> Turns an object whose values are action creators, into an object with the same keys, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly.

This will allow you to do something like `myActions.toggleStuff()` directly without using the dispatch. I like this approach because then I don't have to remember to dispatch as the actions will already be wrapped in it.

For more details the docs are great [LINK](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html)

Comment: Ahhh crap, you are probably right. I cant test this until tomorrow morning, but what your saying makes sense. Ill mark this as correct, and update it tomorrow if I have any problems.

Comment: I typically do import * as actions and put the actions variable directly into connect. This would explain why I'm having problems since I am changing up how I am importing the action

Comment: Oh you're right let me edit, it's like you said `import * as actions`

Comment: Maybe I should just stick with my previous approach, as putting the actions variable straight into the connect function alleviates any need to even define the mapDispatchToProps function in your React Component. For example, export default connect(null, actions)(Your Component) allows you to access your actions directly from this.props without needing a unique identifier in front of it like myActions